# Reading sound card data on RaspberryPi using C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, alsa, soundcard

I want to read the data generated by USB sound card connected to my RaspberryPi using a C code. The samples should be stored in an array or are written to a csv file.

I am using ALSA library through a function "snd_pcm_readi". Can someone explain how to access the data read by "snd_pcm_readi"?

Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: "_I am trying to use ALSA library through a function "snd_pcm_readi" which is not working currently._" - Not working how? Show your attempt in code. Preferably in a [mcve].

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, it looks like this is solely a C question so removing C++ tag.

Comment: The samples returned by `snd_pcm_readi()` are in the format that you have configured.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the libusb library, https://libusb.info/

This library gives you simple C functions to find and open the device, and then send and receive data. You may want to do some reading about USB devices.

You may also want to look at udev - you can write a udev rule to symbolically link the desired device to a known filename.

You may need to know the vendor_id and product_id. At the command line, enter `lsusb` to see the usb devices.